# Android: programmatically added event time is changed on daylight savings

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar, android-calendar

When I add recurring event in android calendar programmatically it is changed by one hour when daylight savings time begin. It adds one hour at the end of March and subtracts one hour at the end of October.

So if I create an event that occurs every day at 8:00 am, at the end of Mart it will be shifted and will start at 9:00 am. It's like this until the end of October. At the end of October it shifts back and until the end of March it's at 8:00 am again.

To mention that the event has `Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE` and `Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE` set, and the calendar this event belongs to has `Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE` set. All of these 3 are set to the same timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem is that I added the time zone in format `GMT+0100`. I have to add time zones if format `Europe/London`.

Comment: Hi @nikmin.. Can you show the code that to deduct the DayLight savings from android app??